# How to strip off element which isNaN using jquery .map

Tags: jquery

I am kind of confusing about the jquery.map function.

I have an array say `myArray = ["1", 3, "a", 5]`.

Can I use `$.map().get().join(',')` to get result of `[1, 3, 5]`;

```
$(myArray).map(function() { 
    if (!isNaN(this)){  
        return this
    }       
}).get().join(',');
```

the above code return `["1","3","a","5"]`

http://jsfiddle.net/kkgian/khurZ/

TIA

Comment: in the fiddle you alert var myArray... try: var $test = $(myArray).map(function() { and alert $test

Comment: `$( array ).map( function )` is not the right way to do it with [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/): instead use: $.map( array, function );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` does not alter the original array. Because your code does not capture the value returned, you're just throwing it away.

Use the (poorly-named) [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function instead of `.map()`. Thanks to the `invert` argument, you don't even have to use an anonymous function; you can use `isNaN` directly as the predicate.

```
var filteredArray = $.grep(myArray, isNaN, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nzeBZ/

**N.B.** `isNaN('1')` returns `false` because `'1'` is a string that can be reasonably coerced to a number. If that's not acceptable, use a better filter predicate. It's a little unclear if you actually want an array of numbers, or just the string `'[1, 3, 5]'`, however.